# Untruncate HTML report dbms_sqltune.report_sql_detail

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

SQL Developer Version -> 19.1
Oracle Version -> Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

```
select dbms_sqltune.report_sql_detail(
  sql_id       => 'query_id',
  type         => 'ACTIVE',
  report_level => 'ALL') as report
from dual;
```

How can I untruncate the HTML code to see the whole of it? It gets truncated with three dots at the end.

```
"(CLOB) <html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   <!--
      var version = "12.1.0.2.0";
     --------------------(more HTML)--------------------------------
x2vwEdQOv8yXWyIwKLiBhIYhNxxzuDvxzo3VvHLjOMOiUJiVSczOu187bWXcetvr
FLA7v+z1JFoFkQ..."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's retuning a CLOB, and you're running this as a query.

If you double click the cell with the '...' in it, it should open to show the the entire contents.

I think it might be easier to see executing as as script.

Try this:

```
set long 1000000
set pagesize 0
clear screen
select dbms_sqltune.report_sql_detail(
  sql_id       => 'f34thrbt8rjt5',
  type         => 'ACTIVE',
  report_level => 'ALL') as report
from dual;
```

Execute as script (F5) is the 2nd execute button. You'll see the output below -

[image]

If you have the SQL statement for your SQL_ID, you can also ask for the SQL Tuning Advisor Report directly there in the SQL Worksheet -

[image]

Note that these features require Enterprise Edition of the database AND the Tuning pack to be licensed.

*Disclaimer: I work for Oracle and am the product manager for SQL Developer.*

Comment: Thanks! Just by clicking the 3 horizontal dots in the cell, the full code appeared without restrictions.